# Concatenating rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)

I'm trying to take data that looks like:

```
User    FieldId     Value
----------------------------
1       1           John
1       2           Smith
2       1           Roberta
2       2           Smith
3       1           Mark
3       2           Smith
```

And convert it to something like:

```
User Name
-------------------
1    John Smith
2    Roberta Smith
3    Mark Smith
```

I found a couple examples at [https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string#:~:text=SQL%20Server%3A%20Concatenate%20Multiple%20Rows%20Into%20Single%20String,version%202008%20and%20higher.%20...%203%20Using%20STRING_AGG](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/concatenate-multiple-rows-into-single-string#:%7E:text=SQL%20Server%3A%20Concatenate%20Multiple%20Rows%20Into%20Single%20String,version%202008%20and%20higher.%20...%203%20Using%20STRING_AGG)

but it doesn't seem to apply to my scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
select user, string_agg(value, ' ') within group(order by fieldid) as name
from mytable
group by user
```

If there are always just 2 `fieldid`s, `1` and `2`, then you conditional aggregation is simpler (and works across all versions of SQL Server):

```
select user,
    max(case when fieldid = 1 then value end) 
        + ' ' 
        + max(case when fieldid = 2 then value end) as name
from mytable
group by user
```

Comment: string_agg is not available in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: As Alejandro wrote string_agg wasn't available in my SQL Server version.  I was able to use the conditional aggregation approach successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have exactly FieldId 1 and 2 everywhere you can use the following code:

```
select x1.User, concat(x1.Value,' ',x2.Value)
FROM
(select User,Value from tablename where FieldId = 1) as x1
inner join
(select User,Value from tablename where FieldId = 2) as x2
on x1.User = x2.User
```

It works by first creating two data sets one with User and value data from the table that had FieldID = 1 and a second one that had FieldID = 2
Looking like this:

```
x1

User         Value
--------------------
1            John
2            Roberta
3            Mark

x2
User         Value
---------------------
1            Smith
2            Smith
3            Smith
```

Then it joins them into a table from which we can trivialy concat the desired string

```
x1.User  x1.Value  x2.Value
----------------------------
1       John        Smith
2       Roberta     Smith
3       Mark        Smith
```